# Проблема в задании по html и js

Tags: javascript, html

onclick не видит функцию p1, хотя я в самом начале подключил js файл

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="kek.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resh.js"></script>
        <title>Лабораторная работа №4</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <form>
                <h1> 1 пример</h1>
                <input id="x" type="text" value="1" />Введите x<br />
                <input id="y" type="text" value="1" />Введите y<br />
                <input type="button" value="Узнать результат" onclick="p1()" />
            </form>
            <h1>
                <div id="result">z=</div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Сам js файл: В нем не видит y

```
function p1() {
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").value);
    if (isNaN(x) == true) x = 0;
    if (isNaN(y) == true) y = 0;
    if y-1/Math.sqrt(x**2+10) === 0 {
        alert("На 0 делить нельзя");
    }
    else {
        var z = (x+(2+y)/x**2)/(y+(1/(Math.sqrt(x**2+10))));
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = z;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка.

вместо

```
if y-1/Math.sqrt(x**2+10) === 0 {
```

надо

```
if (y-1/Math.sqrt(x**2+10) === 0) {
```

---

а файл надо проверить правильность пути до файла... вполне возможно он неправильный. хотя если говорите что функция чего-то не видит, значит файл вполне себе подключен